# Magento 2 : How to concat a string variable to option value in knockout template which already bind to i18n string?

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs, localisation, i18n

I've knockout template which contains the following line:

```
<option value='industrial' data-bind="i18n: 'Industrial'"></option>
```

anyone knows how to add variable to 'Industrial' eg.

```
<option value='industrial' data-bind="i18n: 'Industrial' + window.checkoutConfig.hrFlag"></option>
```

the above line didn't work.

Comment: have you tried doing like this : `data-bind="i18n: 'Industrial + window.checkoutConfig.hrFlag'`?

Comment: @magefms the variable string will not show

Comment: you should declare the variable to the ko bindings function in order to append it in the data-bind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ensure that the text you add in a .js file is collected by the i18n tool and added to the dictionary:

1. Link the mage/translate library

   `define (['jquery', 'mage/translate'], function ($) {...});`
2. Use the `$.mage.__('')` function when adding a string:

   `$.mage.__('<string>');`

If your string contains a variable, to add a placeholder for this variable to the string stored in the dictionary, use the syntax similar to the following:

```
 $.mage.__('Hello %1').replace('%1', yourVariable);
```

In this example, the 'Hello %1' string is added to the dictionary when the i18n tool is run.

**Reference :** https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/translations/translate_theory.html

For phtmls `$t` does the same thing as `mage/translate` so you can do following ;

```
<option value='industrial' data-bind="i18n: $t('Industrial %1').replace('%1', window.checkoutConfig.hrFlag)"></option>
```

Comment: showing error with red cross. by the way, it seems possible to do like this syntax data-bind="attr: {html: $t('Industrial')} , but attr:html is wrong.

Comment: ok try the edit.

Comment: @hkguile the edit worked for you right?

Comment: yes, it works.......

Comment: Ok will add more reference.